# Boost logger linking issue

Tags: c++, logging, boost, c++11

I am writing a program which uses Boost libraries. I had no problems with linking and using program options but I can't seem to make boost log working correctly. 
Could anyone tell me what am I missing?

jamroot.jam

```
using clang : : : <compileflags>-Isrc/main/headers <compileflags>-std=c++11 <compileflags>-stdlib=libc++ <linkflags>-std=c++11 <linkflags>-stdlib=libc++ ;
lib boost_program_options boost_log ;
exe foghorn : [ glob src/main/cpp/*.cpp ] boost_program_options boost_log ;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set::insert(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::add_attribute_unlocked(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::attribute_set_reference_proxy::operator=(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&) const in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set::attribute_set(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::basic_logger(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model> const&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set::attribute_set()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::basic_logger() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set::~attribute_set()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::~basic_logger() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const*) in main.o
  "void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::init_from_stream<char>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      __ZL13gvLoggingInitPKc in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::this_thread::get_id()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_thread_id::impl::dispatch(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_dispatcher&) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_thread_id::impl::detach_from_thread() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::this_process::get_id()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_process_id::current_process_id() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel> >::auto_release::~auto_release() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::get_process_name()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_process_name::current_process_name() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::commit()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::lazy_singleton<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_singleton<SLogger>, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel> > > >::get() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::~once_block_sentry() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::default_attribute_names::severity()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>, ESeverityLevel>::basic_severity_logger() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>, ESeverityLevel>::basic_severity_logger(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>, ESeverityLevel> const&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel> >::~record_pump() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<ESeverityLevel, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::filter const&)", referenced from:
      __ZL13gvLoggingInitPKc in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, ESeverityLevel const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, ESeverityLevel const> const&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::push_record_unlocked(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::add_global_attribute(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&)", referenced from:
      __ZL13gvLoggingInitPKc in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get()", referenced from:
      __ZL13gvLoggingInitPKc in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::basic_logger() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::basic_logger(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<ESeverityLevel>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model> const&) in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::global_storage::get_or_init(std::type_info const&, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder_base> (*)())", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_singleton<SLogger>::init_instance() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::set_value(ESeverityLevel) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::impl::dispatch(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_dispatcher&) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::impl::detach_from_thread() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::throw_odr_violation(std::type_info const&, std::type_info const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder_base const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_singleton<SLogger>::init_instance() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::severity_level() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::impl::~impl() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::impl::detach_from_thread() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::attribute_value_impl<ESeverityLevel>::~attribute_value_impl() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value::impl::~impl() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute::impl::~impl() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_thread_id::current_thread_id() in main.o
      ...
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::severity_level() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<ESeverityLevel>::impl::detach_from_thread() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_thread_id::current_thread_id() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::current_thread_id::impl::detach_from_thread() in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::constant<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process> >::constant(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::id<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::process>&&) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::constant<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::constant(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) in main.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::basic_clock<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::local_time_traits>::basic_clock() in main.o
      ...
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<ESeverityLevel, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name) const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<ESeverityLevel, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::executed() const in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const", referenced from:
      __ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix7sources22basic_composite_loggerIcNS2_15severity_loggerI14ESeverityLevelEENS2_19single_thread_modelENS2_8featuresIJNS2_8severityIS5_EEEEEE11open_recordINS_9parameter3aux15tagged_argumentINS1_8keywords3tag8severityEKS5_EEEENS1_6recordERKT_ in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    "clang++"   -o "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/foghorn" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/complement.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/degenerate.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/fastq.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/fastq_reader.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/interleave.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/interval_reader.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/interval_reader_test_tool.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/main.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/oligo_designer.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/reference_reader.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/reference_reader_test_tool.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/sequence_utils.o" "bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/src/main/cpp/tool.o"  -lboost_log -lboost_program_options  -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

...failed clang-darwin.link bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/foghorn...
...failed updating 1 target...
...updated 13 targets...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue and in my case the problem was that I had boost compiled with dynamic libs only, and forgot to define `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html

As a test, try to compile

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_fmt_stream.cpp

(`#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>` should be added, the example is broken.)

and also add `#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`

I could compile the example with `g++ tutorial_fmt_stream.cpp  -Wall -L$BOOST/lib/ -I $BOOST/include/ -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_filesystem`

Comment: What if you want to link against the static libraries because you don't want to distribute boost along side your library and you want to use a custom built version for cross platform purposes?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `cmake` to manage your boost, just don't forget to have something like:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Different issue but this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, which was a complicated linkage path. The message shows that is trying to link with the static libraries ( ....v2s ...), but the linker is only giving it dynamic libraries (because it is stupid).

Your build of Boost might be generating both `.so` and `.a` files, and gcc gets confused when both are present.

I  had a library built with `CMake` that uses static Boost libraries. If you link this library to a program using a `Makefile` flow, the program needs to also specify the same static Boost libraries. However, the `-l` option for the linker is vague and not your friend here. If you built Boost to have both static (.a) and dynamic (.so) outputs, then the linker will chose the dynamic (.so) files first if you just use the `-l` option.

The workaround is to not use the `-L` and `-l` options to find the Boost static libraries (since it will fail), but to specify the full paths to the Boost libraries. For example,

```
gcc .... -L/opt/boost_1.55/lib -lboost_log
```

change to

```
gcc .... /opt/boost_1.55/lib/libboost_log.a
```

Another option is to specify the word `-static` to gcc, but this requires all libraries to be static, which probably won't work if you use anything besides boost (say the librt.so library).

Comment: another option if you have both and never plan to link boost dynamically: `sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libboost_*.dylib`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::init_from_stream<char>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
```

function, then you need to link

```
libboost_log_setup.a
```